# Xpages SSJS Debugging in external SSJS file

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have got the new 9.0.0 Domino SSJS debugger to work on my Xpages. However, I have a CC inside of an Xpage, and in that CC I have SSJS resource library where I do all my validation.

I can invoke the debugger in any SSJS code EXCEPT in code in the library. It seems the thread just gets "suspended."

OK to clarify. I am trying to debug SSJS in an external library.

The problem is when I get to the 2nd line of code below the debugger seems to no longer be responsive.

The dspDocUNID field is a computed field set to the docUNID (or 0 if a new doc) and I have the attribute display:none on it.

When I run this without debug it runs correctly. When I run it in debug it does not.

```
    control2 = getComponent("dspDocUNID");
    val2 = control2.getValue();
```

Comment: Misunderstood your question, deleted my unrelated answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `getComponent()` code in the SSJS Script Library? `getComponent` doesn't work in a Script Library as far as I know - it doesn't have a context to navigate the component tree to find any components. I would expect it to fail without debug and wouldn't be surprised if it hangs in debug.

Does debugging work if you pass the result of `getComponent("dspDocUNID")` to your function in the SSJS library?

Comment: That is what is weird, is is DOES work in a script library, just not in debug. I have used it for all my validation (getComponent I mean), and it always works. I used some print statements to figure out the problem I was having and found my bug, but it sure is weird that I can't get it to work in the debugger.

Comment: My understanding has always been that it's not recommended to use getComponent in a Script Library because of how it needs to navigate around to try and find a component. The debugger could be affecting its ability to find the context from outside of the XPage.

Comment: That makes sense, Paul. Another programmer here said that he had heard just to not use getComponent. The library I copied this from used getComponent. But I have googled and can't seem to find what to use instead of getComponent. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That other developer probably heard it from Tim Tripcony.This is a good explanatory post http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-9CD3JN. Basically, if the component is bound to a datasource, go to the datasource. If not, pass it as a parameter. this.getParent() can be used to get the component an eventHandler is associated to - e.g a button. If trying to access another component not bound to a datasource or if its value is not set yet, Tim Tripcony again explains using binding property, if you feel confident to try it http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-9GK54N